# Cannot stop Oracle Queue - Could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle9i

Cannot stop and drop oracle Queue.
Following code

```
BEGIN
DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE (
queue_name => 'TEST_QUEUE');

DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE(
queue_name => 'TEST_QUEUE');

END;
/
```

produces following errors:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS", line 3365
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM", line 167
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

What can be the root cause of this problem?

**UPDATE:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS where table_name='DBMS_ASSERT' and GRANTEE='TEST_USER'
...
GRANTEE=TEST_USER
OWNER=SYS
TABLE_NAME=DBMS_ASSERT
GRANTOR=SYS
PRIVILEGE=EXECUTE
GRANTABLE=NO
HIERARCHY=NO

SQL> SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS where table_name='DBMS_AQADM' and GRANTEE='TEST_USER'
...
GRANTEE=TEST_USER
OWNER=SYS
TABLE_NAME=DBMS_AQADM
GRANTOR=SYSTEM
PRIVILEGE=EXECUTE
GRANTABLE=NO
HIERARCHY=NO
```

I’ve checked the table USER_TAB_PRIVS  in a few our schemas and I can see that record with table name 'DBMS_ASSERT' exists in schema with in TEST_USER only.
User have EXECUTE privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like either the DBMS_ASSERT package doesn't exist (unlikely but I suppose possible), or the user you used to log into the database doesn't have execute rights on it.  Typically PUBLIC is granted EXECUTE access to DBMS_ASSERT but perhaps it was changed at your site.  Check EXECUTE permission grants on DBMS_ASSERT and DBMS_AQADM.

Comment: @Vladimir: DBMS_ASSERT is being called by DBMS_AQADM, according to the errors shown in the original message.

Comment: @Vladimir: can you run a test to see what happens if you invoke a routine in DBMS_ASSERT directly?  Try something like

    declare 
      s VARCHAR2(2000);
    begin
      s := DBMS_ASSERT.NOOP('Test string');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('s=''' || s || '''');
    end;

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: s='Test string' PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: @Vladimir: OK, I think that shows your test user can execute code in DBMS_ASSERT successfully.  But it doesn't work when called by code in DBMS_AQADM.  Could you run the following and let me know what the results are?  SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS where table_name IN ('DBMS_AQADM', 'DBMS_ASSERT');

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: TEST_USER SYS DBMS_AQADM SYSTEM EXECUTE NO NO

Comment: @Vladimir: I'm curious what the grants are on DBMS_ASSERT.  I suspect that somehow the SYS user doesn't have execute rights on DBMS_ASSERT and that's why the DBMS_ASSERT call from DBMS_AQADM fails.  DBMS_AQADM is a "definer rights" package and thus executes with the rights of its definer which in this case in the SYS user.  DBMS_ASSERT is an "invoker rights" package and executes with the rights of the caller.  I could be wrong here, but I believe that because DBMS_AQADM (definer rights, as SYS) is calling DBMS_ASSERT (invoker rights) SYS must have execute rights on DBMS_ASSERT.

Comment: @Vladimir: that would depend on your site's policies.  As a developer I'm allowed to do a SELECT from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where I work, but your site may not let you do that.  See if you can run the following query:  SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('DBMS_AQADM', 'DBMS_ASSERT').  If this fails due to permissions issues you may need to ask a DBA to run it for you.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: I have found one difference between two instances of oracle.
On one instance grantor for TEST_USER is SYSTEM.
But on another one grantor for TEST_USER is SYS.
sqlplus TEST_USER/@ora1
SQL> SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('DBMS_AQADM', 'DBMS_ASSERT')
PUBLIC SYS    DBMS_ASSERT  SYS    EXECUTE
TEST_USER     SYS    DBMS_AQADM   SYS    EXECUTE

sqlplus TEST_USER/@ora2
SQL> SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('DBMS_AQADM', 'DBMS_ASSERT')
PUBLIC SYS    DBMS_ASSERT  SYS    EXECUTE      
TEST_USER     SYS    DBMS_AQADM   SYSTEM EXECUTE

Comment: @Vladimir: Thanks for your response.  It looks like PUBLIC has EXECUTE privileges on DBMS_ASSERT, so SYS and everyone else should be able to run code in DBMS_ASSERT just fine.  (I don't think that the grantor should matter).  Perhaps this is the wrong issue.  @dpbradley may have hit upon something - has DBMS_ASSERT (or something it calls) gone invalid somehow?

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: We just updated Oracle to the last patch level 10.2.0.5.
Now we do not have any problems with queues.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you've made this call before without any problems, then the ORA-04068 error makes me think that something in the calling chain has been invalidated.  Have you applied any upgrades or patches to the installation recently?

Oracle supplies a script, utlrp in $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin, that will recompile all of the packages and report on any remaining invalid.  Have your administrator run that (as SYS).

Comment: We have such problem only on one schema. All other schemas on the same server works today without any errors.
But I asks our DBA team.